# AWS sdk for .net queryAsync method using global secondary index fails

Tags: c#-4.0, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, secondary-indexes

given below is the method I used to retrieve details from a Dynamodb table. But when I call this method it ended up throwing an exception "Unable to locate property for key attribute appointmentId". primary key of this particular table is appointmentId, but I've already created a global secondary index on patientId column. I'm using that index in below query to get the appointment details by a given patientID.

```
public async Task GetAppointmentByPatientID(int patientID)
        {
            var context = CommonUtils.Instance.DynamoDBContext;


            PatientAppointmentObjectList.Clear();


            DynamoDBOperationConfig config = new DynamoDBOperationConfig();
            config.IndexName = DBConstants.APPOINTMENT_PATIENTID_GSI;
            AsyncSearch<ScheduledAppointment> appQuery = context.QueryAsync<ScheduledAppointment>(patientID.ToString(), config);
            IEnumerable<ScheduledAppointment> appList = await appQuery.GetRemainingAsync();

            appList.Distinct().ToList().ForEach(i => PatientAppointmentObjectList.Add(i));

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                this.OnPropertyChanged("PatientAppointmentObjectList");
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the index name in your query? Do you create an extra index or it is simply the name of your database?

Comment: I had your problem and it was driving me mad. My DynamoDBHashKey didn't exist but the message said "Id" and that wasn' t the right column name

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It was a silly mistake. I've had the hash key column of the table as "appointmentID" and the model object property named as AppointmentID. mismatch in the case of the property name had confused the dynamodb mapping.

Comment: Wanted to add that, if you require to have specific naming on DynamoDB however want to use different casing like pascal case as we usually do for properties you can do use the `[DynamoDBProperty("year")], [DynamoDBHashKey("title")]` etc above your property named Year, Title etc.